# JQuery Mobile UI Editor - Codiqa Alternative

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Is there a FREE and or OPEN SOURCE UI Editor similar to the Codiqa editor found on the [JQuery Mobile home page](http://jquerymobile.com/)?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a free one available here

https://01.org/rib/

It only works in Chrome but that should not be a problem. You can download the source and host it locally on your personal web server. Then you can make whatever changes you want since you have the source.

You can also open Chrome with

--enable-file-cookies --allow-file-access-from-files

and then CTRL+O to open the index.hrml locally without using a web server.

You can even install it as a Chrome app extension.

You just need to give it permission to store files locally as it stores your projects locally.

Try it and see. It actually works, though the native source uses JQM 1.0 but that can easily be changed to use v1.3 - the latest release.

Answer (score 8):

There are two other editors available

http://www.mobjectify.com/

and

http://tiggzi.com/home

Comment: I believe he asked for free or open-source.

Comment: Above both links are dead

Answer (score 3):

Use [Intel XDK New](http://xdk-software.intel.com/).it supports more than 3 UI development frameworks (JQMobile,Intel App Framework,etc).its free and open source

Comment: nice to know. i will post a review after tinkering with this tool.

Comment: intel XDK new can be use for UI designing part.then you can take www folder out and can use it with eclips+phonegap environment. it works with phonegap with no issue.i tested it many times.

Comment: designing? you mean manually write the html code at the text editor right?

Comment: i think you never used intel xdk new.not manually writing the code.we can drag and drop all most all the UI components which are available in native android app (even side bar). and we can select 4 UI designing environments.  here is the url http://xdk-software.intel.com/

Comment: my bad. i was using blank project instead of app designer. they should put it at the top or as a default. thanks. it very helpful. :)

Answer (score 2):

July edit: We have experimented with a "free" plan before, and just couldn't find a good formula. We're a small team so we decided to take away a free plan for new signups until we can learn more about how to make a good one, if ever.

However, we do offer free accounts for students, people working on open source code, or non-profits.

Comment: I did find that out after posting this question, but i would still like one that is open source (I have changed my question to show this). Basically I want one that i can extend, and add my own templates. I started my own the day i asked this question, and am getting close to where I want to be now. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Well if you feel like talking with us outside of SO, just send us an email. Curious to hear about your project and how we can open ours to make it easier to add stuff to and modify.

Comment: [Here is the plans page](http://codiqa.com/plans). I don't see any that are free, though there is a 30-day free trial. If you are going to misrepresent your pricing in this manner, then I have to seriously consider entering into a long-term dependency on your tool.

Comment: There was a link to a "Free" version before.  I'm guessing it is no longer available.

Comment: @DOK we aren't trying to misrepresent anything. We are a young company that has tried lots of experiments and we are just learning what works and what doesn't. We've turned off our free plan for new accounts since June, though we do now offer free plans for students, non-profits, open source projects, etc. The free plan didn't match up to the costs of providing the service. We've also released cheaper plans ($7/mo for our google drive version in the chrome store).

Comment: @Max - just tried out your product which is pretty nice. It is still not perfect, like adding components to a collapsible object. What I really don't like is mispresenating the pricing. The "from $XX/mo" instead of plainly writing the actual amount rather than having me prepare a project and then discover that downloading the code is premium, fair enough, but when I want to pay I discover it is not just $16 a month, but $24. You lost me as a customer.

Comment: @Max `though we do now offer free plans for students, non-profits, open source projects, etc` I'm both student and want to make open source app. Sent an email. No reply.

Answer (score 1):

Give [EZoApp](http://jqmdesigner.appspot.com/designer.html) a try，it's totally free and easy to get started ! Besides, Many rich extensible components are offered.

Comment: Update; it's free basic feature only, 3 pages max. enough good just for "try and fly"